# how to bind an image to RadImageEditorUI in WPF

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wpf, .net-4.0

I'm very new in WPF and in which i'm using RadImageEditorUI. Actually I want to bind an image url to the RadImageEditor. I not know how to bind the image URL to the Rad Image editor. I have the following designer code.

```
 <telerik:RadImageEditorUI Name="radImageEditor">
        <telerik:RadImageEditorUI.ImageToolsSections>
            <telerik:ImageToolsSection telerik:LocalizationManager.ResourceKey="ImageEditor_Transform">
                <telerik:ImageToolItem Command="{x:Static telerik:ImageEditorRoutedCommands.ExecuteTool}" ImageKey="Resize" telerik:LocalizationManager.ResourceKey="ImageEditor_Resize">
                    <telerik:ImageToolItem.CommandParameter>
                        <Tools:ResizeTool/>
                    </telerik:ImageToolItem.CommandParameter>
                </telerik:ImageToolItem>
                <telerik:ImageToolItem Command="{x:Static telerik:ImageEditorRoutedCommands.ExecuteTool}" ImageKey="Resize" telerik:LocalizationManager.ResourceKey="ImageEditor_CanvasResize">
                    <telerik:ImageToolItem.CommandParameter>
                        <Tools:CanvasResizeTool/>
                    </telerik:ImageToolItem.CommandParameter>
                </telerik:ImageToolItem>
                <telerik:ImageToolItem Command="{x:Static telerik:ImageEditorRoutedCommands.Rotate90Clockwise}" ImageKey="Rotate90CW" telerik:LocalizationManager.ResourceKey="ImageEditor_Rotate90"/>
                <telerik:ImageToolItem Command="{x:Static telerik:ImageEditorRoutedCommands.Rotate180}" ImageKey="Rotate180CW" telerik:LocalizationManager.ResourceKey="ImageEditor_Rotate180"/>
                <telerik:ImageToolItem Command="{x:Static telerik:ImageEditorRoutedCommands.Rotate90Counterclockwise}" ImageKey="Rotate90CCW" telerik:LocalizationManager.ResourceKey="ImageEditor_Rotate270"/>
                <telerik:ImageToolItem Command="{x:Static telerik:ImageEditorRoutedCommands.ExecuteTool}" ImageKey="RoundCorners" telerik:LocalizationManager.ResourceKey="ImageEditor_RoundCorners">
                    <telerik:ImageToolItem.CommandParameter>
                        <Tools:RoundCornersTool/>
                    </telerik:ImageToolItem.CommandParameter>
                </telerik:ImageToolItem>
                <telerik:ImageToolItem Command="{x:Static telerik:ImageEditorRoutedCommands.FlipHorizontal}" ImageKey="FlipHorizontal" telerik:LocalizationManager.ResourceKey="ImageEditor_FlipHorizontal"/>
                <telerik:ImageToolItem Command="{x:Static telerik:ImageEditorRoutedCommands.FlipVertical}" ImageKey="FlipVertical" telerik:LocalizationManager.ResourceKey="ImageEditor_FlipVertical"/>
                <telerik:ImageToolItem Command="{x:Static telerik:ImageEditorRoutedCommands.ExecuteTool}" ImageKey="Crop" telerik:LocalizationManager.ResourceKey="ImageEditor_Crop">
                    <telerik:ImageToolItem.CommandParameter>
                        <Tools:CropTool/>
                    </telerik:ImageToolItem.CommandParameter>
                </telerik:ImageToolItem>
                <telerik:ImageToolItem Command="{x:Static telerik:ImageEditorRoutedCommands.ExecuteTool}" ImageKey="DrawText" telerik:LocalizationManager.ResourceKey="ImageEditor_DrawText">
                    <telerik:ImageToolItem.CommandParameter>
                        <Tools:DrawTextTool/>
                    </telerik:ImageToolItem.CommandParameter>
                </telerik:ImageToolItem>
            </telerik:ImageToolsSection>
            <telerik:ImageToolsSection telerik:LocalizationManager.ResourceKey="ImageEditor_Adjust">
                <telerik:ImageToolItem Command="{x:Static telerik:ImageEditorRoutedCommands.ExecuteTool}" ImageKey="HueShift" telerik:LocalizationManager.ResourceKey="ImageEditor_Effect_HueShift">
                    <telerik:ImageToolItem.CommandParameter>
                        <Tools:HueShiftTool/>
                    </telerik:ImageToolItem.CommandParameter>
                </telerik:ImageToolItem>
                <telerik:ImageToolItem Command="{x:Static telerik:ImageEditorRoutedCommands.ExecuteTool}" ImageKey="Saturation" telerik:LocalizationManager.ResourceKey="ImageEditor_Effect_Saturation">
                    <telerik:ImageToolItem.CommandParameter>
                        <Tools:SaturationTool/>
                    </telerik:ImageToolItem.CommandParameter>
                </telerik:ImageToolItem>
                <telerik:ImageToolItem Command="{x:Static telerik:ImageEditorRoutedCommands.ExecuteTool}" ImageKey="Contrast" telerik:LocalizationManager.ResourceKey="ImageEditor_Effect_ContrastAdjust">
                    <telerik:ImageToolItem.CommandParameter>
                        <Tools:ContrastTool/>
                    </telerik:ImageToolItem.CommandParameter>
                </telerik:ImageToolItem>
                <telerik:ImageToolItem Command="{x:Static telerik:ImageEditorRoutedCommands.InvertColors}" ImageKey="Invert" telerik:LocalizationManager.ResourceKey="ImageEditor_Effect_InvertColors">
                    <telerik:ImageToolItem.CommandParameter>
                        <Tools:ContrastTool/>
                    </telerik:ImageToolItem.CommandParameter>
                </telerik:ImageToolItem>
            </telerik:ImageToolsSection>
            <telerik:ImageToolsSection telerik:LocalizationManager.ResourceKey="ImageEditor_Effects">
                <telerik:ImageToolItem Command="{x:Static telerik:ImageEditorRoutedCommands.ExecuteTool}" ImageKey="Sharpen" telerik:LocalizationManager.ResourceKey="ImageEditor_Effect_Sharpen">
                    <telerik:ImageToolItem.CommandParameter>
                        <Tools:SharpenTool/>
                    </telerik:ImageToolItem.CommandParameter>
                </telerik:ImageToolItem>
                <telerik:ImageToolItem Command="{x:Static telerik:ImageEditorRoutedCommands.ExecuteTool}" ImageKey="Blur" telerik:LocalizationManager.ResourceKey="ImageEditor_Effect_Blur">
                    <telerik:ImageToolItem.CommandParameter>
                        <Tools:BlurTool/>
                    </telerik:ImageToolItem.CommandParameter>
                </telerik:ImageToolItem>
            </telerik:ImageToolsSection>
        </telerik:RadImageEditorUI.ImageToolsSections>
    </telerik:RadImageEditorUI>
```

and i'm not using silverlight. Its purely WPF application. What I need to do?